# Is there a standard for text alignment inside of username and password input boxes?

Tags: input-fields, standards, alignment

I am working on designing a login window, and began to wonder if there is a standard for aligning text in an input box.

A particular note here is that the username and password fields and boxes are center aligned with the window, so I thought maybe it would make sense to center align the text within the input boxes.

Is there a standard for when to use left-aligned input v.s. center-aligned input? Is there any research on the effects this has on users?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user can type in the input directly, **align the text input to the left** (to the right on RTL languages). If you follow this rule then the label looks strange center-aligned. So align it to the left too. You can center the container in the page and leave the Next button either left or right aligned.

If the text is not entered in the input directly typing (like a Pin code where the number of characters is fixed) then the input can be center-aligned. (In this case you might want to remove the borders of the input.)